# Datagridview compare cell string

Tags: c#, string, datagridview, compare

I need to compare 2 String-Values in one cell.(if in cell 1 is a string like 'DPS' and 'MAN')
But I dont know why my && Operator does not work like i think. I dont get an Result.

[image]

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

```
private void Warning()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
        if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "DPS" 
            && row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "MAN")
        {
            panelWarnung.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            panelWarning.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
}
```

SOLUTION

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
            if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("DPS") == row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("MAN"))
                panelWarning.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

SOLUTION II (Check Entire Column for both values)

```
int dps = 0; int man = 0; 

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
            if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "DPS") dps++; else if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "MAN") man++; 
        if (man > 0 && dps > 0 && abc > 0)
        {
            panelWarnung.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

Comment: Riddle me this. How can you make a single variable simultaneously equal to two different values? `string x = "something here"` - what do you replace `"something here"` with that means *equals "DPS" and also equals "MAN"* is true? If you make it "DPS", then *equals "MAN"* is false. If you make it "MAN" then *equals "DPS"* is false.. What's the solution?

Comment: The Solution should be:
if DPS and MAN is in the cell the warningPanel should turn red

Comment: So, you want `Contains`, not `Equals` ..

Comment: What your picture shows and your comments of what you want appear to be two (2) different things. Your last comment states that … _”The Solution should be: if DPS and MAN is in the cell the warningPanel should turn red_” … ? … Where in the picture does ONE (1) cell in the grid contain BOTH “MAN” AND “DPS”?

Comment: You are now checking whether the statuses for "DPS" and "MAN" are the same for a cell - that is, whether they both exist (will give true), or both do not exist (also true). If a cell contains one, but not the other, then you will get false. I'm not sure that is exactly what you were looking for..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>I've undeleted this answer because, since seeing your screenshot, I've realized it's actually quite relevant</sub>

---

**This answer is for if a cell on some row will have MAN or another cell on another row will have DPS in the cell**

For example, cells like:

```
MAN  
ext
DPS  
wow
MAN  
MAN
```

This is usually a psychology thing, I suspect coming from the way people speak when they talk about collections of things:

> Get all the red and green fruits out of this box

If you gave this task to a human they would probably give you a handful of red fruit and also a handful of green fruit..

..but that was actually "or"

> Look through this box, and if a fruit is red **or** if it is green, take it out and give it to me

We've put the request in terms of each individual fruit, which means it doesn't make sanse with "and" any more:

> Look through this box, and if a fruit is red **and** if it is green, take it out and give it to me

C# will be considering your rows on a row-by-row basis, if you want the MAN rows to be red and you also want the DPS rows to be red, then you need to use `||` or. From a human perspective you're using *and* across the entire collection when you say "the MAN ones are red and the DPS ones are red".. But when you're processing items individually you cannot say "if it's MAN and DPS, make it red".. you say "if it's MAN or its DPS; make it red"

Instead you need:

```
row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "DPS" || row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "MAN")
                                       ^^
                                 note the OR, not AND
```

Overall, I'd recommend a code of:

```
private void Warning()
{
    panelWarning.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
        if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()== "DPS" || row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "MAN")
            row.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = panelWarnung.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else
            row.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

This will light up any individual cells in red if they are MAN or DPS, and the warning panel in red

---

Edit, and a slight tweak to the logic: if you want the checking to operate across rows so that if at least one cell is MAn and at least one other cell is DPS you light up the panel, then you can count all the occurrences:

```
    int dps = 0; 
    int man = 0; 
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows){
      if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "DPS") 
        dps++; 
      else if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "MAN") 
        man++; 
    }

    if (man > 0 && dps > 0) { 
      panelWarnung.BackColor = Color.Red; 
    }
```

This could be shortened with LINQ to just:

```
var vals = dataGridView4.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow().Select(r => r.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
if(rows.Any(v => v == "MAN") && rows.Any(v => v == "DPS"))
  panelWarnung.BackColor = Color.Red; 
else
  panelWarnung.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
```

It's conceptually the same thing but actually a bit more performant because it doesn't count every one; it just gets every value in the column, as a string, then it asks "is any of these values "MAN"? and is any of these values "DPS"?" -> warning. Else -> clear

Comment: If you have both values in a cell, then the cell value must be like `MAN,DPS` and you should use Contains (the other answer). Just so we're clear: a `cell` is one box that you type in. Like, A1 or B7 in excel. A `column` is a whole vertical line of many boxes, like A or B in excel.. You canot use `==` and `&&` together on the same cell

Comment: To change the color of a label, set `theLabel.ForeColor = ...` to some color, like you do the `panelWarning.BackColor`

Comment: That's what the `foreach` loop does.. it compares one cell at a time, all the way down the entire column (it does "for each row in the grid", always looking at `Cells[1]` which effecitvely travels down the second column, row by row)

Comment: If you're asking "how can I detect if at least one row in the column says MAN and at least one other row says "DPS", then you can keep a counter in your loop: `int dps = 0; int man = 0; foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows) if(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()== "DPS") dps++; else if(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()== "MAN") man++;` - at the end of the loop you will have counted the number of each, so you can `if(man>0 && dps>0)`

Comment: See the comment I posted just before yours - i think it's what you're asking

Comment: No problem! I'll transfer that advice into the answer so it's more enduring (comments can be removed for any reason) and you can mark it as accepted if you like..

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is for when a single cell will hold a string that has both MAN and DPS inside**

For example, cells like:

```
MANDPS
DPS,MAN
DPSinghs MANager
```

> if DPS and MAN is in the cell the warningPanel should turn red

That's

```
row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("DPS") 
    && row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("MAN")
```

`Contains` tests whether the string is present somewhere within the cell. `==` tests whether the entire whole string in the cell is exactly equal to some value.. And no variable can be simultaneously equal to two different values

Overall, I'd recommend a code of:

```
private void Warning()
{
    panelWarning.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
        if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("DPS") && row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("MAN"))
            row.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = panelWarnung.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else
            row.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Comment: Thats helped alot! Thank you!

Comment: KJartan makes a good point; you might want to, as well as turn one panel red, also highlight the cell that is in error too: `row.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red` .. and perhaps remove the `else` entirely: set your panel green before your `foreach` loop and then turn it red inside with the `if`.. If the loop gets to the end then and no cells are in error the panel is green. If one or more cells are error, then the panel goes red, and also the cells are highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Changed answer in response to comments below:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
    if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("DPS")
            && row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("MAN")) {
        panelWarnung.BackColor = Color.Red;
        break; // <-- NB: Stop the loop after the first invalid cell!
    }
```

Now your panel should be set to the specified color if *both* DPS and MAN is contained in one of the cells.

**NOTE however** that you'll also need to add the `break` statement after setting the color to red, otherwise you risk it being overridden and set to whatever result is found for the *last* row.

Comment: Thank you very much for your Help! 
Here is the working Solution. You helped me alot.
Have a great week!

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView4.Rows)
                if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("DPS") == row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains("MAN"))
                    panelWarning.BackColor = Color.Red;

Comment: @David Hm.. that is not exactly what I added... and it seems a little suspicious ;). You are now checking whether the statuses for "DPS" and "MAN" are the same for a cell - that is, whether they both exist (will give `true`), or both do *not* exist (also `true`). If a cell contains one, but not the other, then you will get `false`. I'm not sure that is exactly what you were looking for..?

Comment: Maybe I was not specific enough.

I need those 2 Values to change the color of my Panel.
That does now exactly what I need. :)

Comment: @David Ok - I've adjusted my answer to match what I think you need now. As for you own solution, I still think you'll have an error there: If neither of the values are contained, then that logic will still produce a `true` result, which would make your panel red by mistake. Also, it would be overridden by whatever is in the last row, so you'll still probably need the `break` statement too.